# change popover hight and unhide a new area

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, position, popover

Good morning,

I have this litte example (swift 4 for macOS):

**Storyboard**

[image]

**Result**

[image]

In my popover are three buttons.
I have an IBAction on the grey button.

Now I would like to realize the following situation, if I press the grey button:

[image]

- I would like to change the height of my popover
- the textfields under the grey button should be hide.
- the two white buttons should move up

To change the height of my popover I tried this with success:

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: NSButton) {

   self.view.window?.animator().setFrame(
   NSRect(origin: CGPoint(x: self.view.window!.frame.origin.x, y: self.view.window!.frame.origin.y), size: CGSize(width: self.view.window!.frame.width, height: self.view.window!.frame.height - 100)), display: true, animate: true)

}
```

I know, that I can hide the text fields like this: `mytextfield.isHidden = true` but how can i move up the two white buttons on the same position, where the textfields were shown before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the position of the buttons at where textField is.

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: NSButton) {
    textField.isHidden = true
    textField2.isHidden = true
    buttonA.frame.origin.y = (textField.frame.origin.y + textField2.frame.origin.y)/2
    buttonB.frame.origin.y = (textField.frame.origin.y + textField2.frame.origin.y)/2
}
```

Comment: thanks for your solution. meanwhile I found another way to do this. in my storyboard I set the the vertical spacing between the white and grey button, connect this constraint via IBOutlet and set the constraint value to 10 (instead the default 100). thanks a lot :)